# Does workbox-precache check the integrity of fetched files?

Tags: workbox

Afaik, in order for workbox precache to keep track of precached files, a md5 hash is created of the file and used as the file's revision number in `sw.js` (see [get-asset-hash.js](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/master/packages/workbox-webpack-plugin/src/lib/get-asset-hash.js) and  [generate-sw.js](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/master/packages/workbox-webpack-plugin/src/generate-sw.js#L75-L78))

After fetching the file, does workbox create a md5 hash of the new file and compare its value with the revision number in `sw.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workbox doesn't seem to check the integrity of the new file via md5 (see [PrecacheController.mjs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/master/packages/workbox-precaching/controllers/PrecacheController.mjs#L245-L275), [cacheWrapper.mjs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/master/packages/workbox-core/_private/cacheWrapper.mjs#L27-L103) and [PrecachedDetailsModel.mjs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/master/packages/workbox-precaching/models/PrecachedDetailsModel.mjs#L113-L129))